# populate dynamic array from segue swift

Tags: arrays, swift, segue

for the first view i prepare to segue 3 textFields:(Sorry for my bad english as well)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "salvar") {
        var view = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondView
        view.end = endereco.text
        view.area = area.text
        view.data = data.text 
    }
}
```

the problem is on secondView the array is repeating (and don't add new data to array, only replace it), making the 3 labels from cell repeating with the same data, heres the secondView code:

```
class secondView: UITableViewController {

var end = ""
var area = ""
var data = ""

var array: [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.array = [end, area, data]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.array.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AgendaCell

    cell.label1.text = self.array[indexPath.row] as String
    cell.label2.text = self.array[indexPath.row] as String               
    cell.label3.text = self.array[indexPath.row] as String

    return cell
}
```

how i can really add new data to array, and place each for the ordered label from cell?

Comment: You are populating an array with three items, you've told your table view to show three cells, but you then have a `cellForRowAtIndexPath` which is updating three labels for each cell (i.e. for a total of nine labels), which is probably not what you wanted. On the basis of what you've shared with us to far, this doesn't seem like a good application of table view at all. Sounds like you just want a plain old `UIViewController` that has no table, but rather only three labels. (Or if it was table, make it static table with IBOutlets.) Perhaps you can explain the rationale for making this a table?

Comment: OK, I'm segue 3 textFields for a UIViewController, i'm trying to save the fields content to cell labels, for example every time the user press save from the first view it segue this fields to tableView, i did this using Parse, save in Parse class and call the column were its save, but i wan't do it without Parse, if possible.